# JQuery DataTables 1.8.1 Checkbox - code equivalence

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'am using datatable 1.8.1 and ajax-source to render my tables.

I am trying to check/uncheck all checkboxes with one 'main' checkbox.

My checkboxes are on different page with the pagination functionality of dataTables. That's why i can not select the id or class of checkboxes because this will only select checkboxes which are on my current page.

I do have make some research and i have found and tried code below :

```
dt.rows().nodes().to$().find('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled)').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
```

where dt is an instance of my Datatable :

```
var dt   = $('#selector').dataTable();
```

But it shows that dt.rows() is not a function. Maybe my version of Datatable is too old ? Does some one have any idea or equivalence of the code that i mentioned just above?

**EDIT**

datatable

```js
        var dt   = $('#newsletter_contact_datatable').dataTable();
        var opts = dt.fnSettings();
        opts.aoDrawCallback.push({
            fn: function() {
                var form                = $(this).closest('form');
                var container           = form.find('.element-ids_js');
                var values              = container.val() ? JSON.parse(container.val()) : [];
                var blacklist_container = form.find('.element-blacklisted-ids_js');
                var blacklist_values    = blacklist_container.val() ? JSON.parse(blacklist_container.val()) : [];
        
                $('input[name="element-ids[]"]').each(function() {
                    var val = parseInt($(this).val());
        
                    if(blacklist_values.includes(val)) {
                        $(this).prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', true);
                        $(this).closest('tr').find('.blacklisted_js').removeClass('black').addClass('red').text('Annuler');
                    } else {
                        $(this).prop('checked', true).prop('disabled', false);
                        $(this).closest('tr').find('.blacklisted_js').removeClass('red').addClass('black').text('Retirer');
        
                        if(values.includes(val)) {
                            $(this).prop('checked', false);
                        }
                    }
                });
        
                $('input[name="check_all"]').prop('checked', true);
            },
            sName: 'user'
        });
// REFRESH DATATABLE WITH FILTERS
$('.box-filter input, .box-filter select').on('change', function() {
    refreshDatatable($(this));
});
refreshDatatable($('#newsletter_contact_datatable'));

function refreshDatatable($this) {
    var $form        = $this.closest('form');
    opts.sAjaxSource = "{{ path('template_path') }}?" + $form.serialize();
    dt.fnDraw();
}
$('form table input[name="check_all"]').on('change', function() {
                dt.api().rows().nodes().to$().find('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled)').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
            });
```

```html
    <div class="grid grid_18">
        <table id="newsletter_contact_datatable" class="data display datatable" data-sort="[[1, 'asc']]" data-ajax-source="{{ path('template_path') }}">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="no_sort"><input type="checkbox" name="check_all" value="check_all" checked /></th>
                    <th width="15%">Lastname</th>
                    <th width="15%">First-name</th>
                    <th width="55%">Email</th>
                    <th class="no_sort" width="10%">Blacklist ?</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>

Template :

    <input type="checkbox" name="element-ids[]" value="{{ obj.id }}" checked />
    
    <div>{{ obj.data.lastname }}</div>
    
    <div>{{ obj.data.firstname }}</div>
    
    <div>
        {{ email.label }}
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn black tiny blacklisted_js" data-id="{{ obj.id }}">Delete</button>
```

A sample of data would be :

checkbox - john - doe - johndoe@email.com - button blacklist

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
var dt = $('#selector').dataTable();
```

Use this:

```
var dt = $('#selector').DataTable();
```

In other words, notice the use of `DataTable` instead of `datatable`.

What is the difference? As described in [this documentation page](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) for the DataTables API:

> *It is important to note the difference between `$( selector ).DataTable()` and `$( selector ).dataTable()`. The former returns a DataTables API instance, while the latter returns a jQuery object.*

You can see from the documentation the 3 different ways to access the DataTables API object. Therefore an alternative approach which still uses `dataTable` when assigning `dt` is:

```
dt.api();
```

---

**Update** for version 1.8

I completely missed the fact that you are using 1.8 (clearly mentioned in the question). My apologies - that changes all the syntax. My notes above are only relevant for 1.10 onwards.

For 1.8, try this:

Your starting point:

```
var dt = $('#newsletter_contact_datatable').dataTable();
```

Using the `dt` variable, you can then use the following:

```
$(dt.fnGetNodes()) // 1.8 syntax
```

This is the equivalent of the 1.10 syntax you were trying to use:

```
dt.rows().nodes().to$() // 1.10 syntax
```

From this point, you should be able to use the rest of your jQuery syntax `.find(...)` to locate the checkboxes for the entire table.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. i'am adding api() to dt and it returns the same error : Uncaught TypeError: dt.api is not a function.  `dt.api().rows().nodes().to$().find('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled)').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));`

Comment: Understood. Show us enough code so that we can recreate your issue, in the same way that it is happening for you. So, a [mre] with your DataTable code, your HTML and a sample of your data.

Comment: Hi, i just add some code in my Edits, let me know if you need more information. Thanks.